# How to populate list on another page from XML in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

What I want to do is using JQuery Mobile I want to dynamically load content on #newPage depending on what option I clicked.  Below is the code I tried that goes to #newPage, but does not load any content.  I tried to give as much info as possible and commented line by line to what I wanted it to do.

Sample XML:

```
<parentOption>
    <option1>
        <name>Stuff</name>
    </option1>
    <potion2>
        <name>More Stuff</name>
    </potion2>
    <option3>
       <name>Even More Stuff</name>
    </option3>
</parentOption>
```

Assume I have connected to the XML file via Ajax:

```
<script>
    function parseXML(xml) { //Parse the XML
        $('selected').click(function(e) { //Once the link is clicked
            var selectedValue = $(this).value(); //Find the value of the clicked link
            e.preventDefault(); //Refresh the new page
            $(xml).find(selectedValue).each(function() { //take the XML info and select all of the elements equaling to the value of the selected link
                var nameValue = $(this).parent(); //Find the parent of the selected element
                $('#dynamicList').append('<li>' + $(nameValue).child('name').text() + '</li>'); //Write out the list on the new page
            });
            $('#dynamicList').listview('refresh');
        });
     }
 </script>
 <div data-role="page" id="home">
     <div data-role="content">
         <ul data-role="listview">
             <li><a class="selected" value="option1" href="#newPage">Option 1</a></li>
             <li><a class="selected" value="option1" href="#newPage">Option 2</a></li>
             <li><a class="selected" value="option1" href="#newPage">Option 3</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="newPage">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="dynamicList" data-role="listview">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the desired output after clicking the first link:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a class="selected" value="option1" href="#newPage">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="selected" value="option1" href="#newPage">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="selected" value="option1" href="#newPage">Option 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div data-role="page" id="newPage">
     <div data-role="content">
         <ul id="dynamicList" data-role="listview">
             <li>Stuff</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there are a typos... `dqta-role="content"` should be `data-role="content"`... you do not use a jQuery listview, is this as desired? using a jQuery listview you just could refresh the listview after building it...

Comment: Sorry about the typos,  this block of code is just an example I typed up to be a generic as possible.  As for the $('#dynamicList').listview('refresh'),  I did forget to add that after the .each(function()...

Comment: which means, you also **forgot** the `data-role="listview"` in your example? `<ul id="dynamicList" data-role="listview"></ul>` probably you try to put together a correct example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you a working example, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AzXdT/. Also I need to give you a warning, this example works only in jsFiddle because you can't load xml's from other domains. If you want to load xml from your domain (your hosting server) use this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sites.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

    }
});
```

If possible use JSON instead of XML. Reason, complex XML can be big in size with a lot of data overhead. JSON is created with idea to fix this problem. In case you want to try it I made you another example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8uac7/. This example can be used everywhere so feel free to play with it.

Comment: Thanks,  Upon writing the question I only was able to use an XML file but, am having it switched to json.